# How to inherit a Spring Boot project (both Java code and views) on Maven?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I had developed a basic project(with Spting Boot) contains some module(like user, log ,authority e.g.), and structure like below:

[image]

The basic project is a complete project, it can run directlly and I can do something from the browser.

Now, I want to create a new project base on demo-scala(mentioned above), new project will inherit all things from demo-scala and I just need to add the new business java code & html files.

I try to do with below on pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zeus</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-scala</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

On new project I create some controllers and html files
[image]

I run the new project ,and controllers can be scaned. But when I call some controllers on browser it takes error.
And if I delete "templates" folder on new project , it is fine.

How can I deal with this problem . Or is there a better way to fix my situation? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure you can really do this, inheriting and re-using code is one thing, but things like html pages, even if you manage to package them some how, they need to be deployed property and be visible to whatever  web container. I would suggest, you start gradually, isolate the code, package it as a jar, add is a dependency to the new war . Make sure though that certain classes that need to be visible and accessible to the container- are in place. Just copy the html files and resources all over among with the new stuff

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will try it.